# ClassNotFoundException when connecting to an Azure databse

Tags: java, database, azure, mariadb, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to connect a Java application to an Azure database stored in the cloud. I keep receiving the ClassNotFoundException when running

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc");
```

I am experienced with Java, but new to connecting a Java application to a database. I have downloaded and included

"mariadb-java-client-2.5.2-sources.jar"

in my project. Are there any other jar files I should be including? If not what else do I need to do to prevent this error from occurring? If it helps I am using Eclipse.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm not using a maven project. Also, I have included what looks like to be that jar already